Deactivate "tabledrag", another item, order for comments
I need a very simple forum function for my site and I am currently trying out the forum module in Drupal Core. My Drupal is version 10.1.8.
But now there are the buttons "preview" and "add another item" under the comment function and to the right of the comment function there is also a sort function. In the code itself, this appears as a tabledrag function, but modules such as draggable views or weight are not built in.
Can I hide these functions somehow, because I don't actually need them and the function is just a nuisance?
I couldn't find anything about this in the module itself or in the permissions. With the sorting function, I don't understand why it is needed?
In the screenshot I have marked again what I would like to have deactivated
Would be very grateful for any help or ideas.
Thanks and best regards
Bavra


Would an ordinary hook_form_alter implementation do this?
